# Are these three quadratic regressions statistically different? Any statistical analysis?

Tags: regression

I obtained several data from three different samples. I plotted them in order to see individually their regressions. You can see it below:
[image]

Is there any statistical analysis which let to know if they are different? I would expect not finding differences between the green and black lines. Otherwise, the red line seems to be far from the other two, thus I would expect to find differences.

Thanks for your answers and commens.

Comment: What kinds of differences do you want to detect? For instance, although the green and black curves are close, I get the impression that variation of the data around the green curve is larger than variation around the black one. There is also a (somewhat bizarre) pattern of strong negative serial correlation evident in all the data. This could have an important influence on testing the differences between the locations of the curves, so you would want to understand and model this behavior. I would guess there's a third variable, such as an experiment identifier, that plays an important role.

Comment: Sorry for the time lapsed. I've been abroad with no internet access. Thanks for your comment whuber. I've found that in R Commander it's possible to compare models (using ANOVA) and I interpret it as a possibility to compare two by two my quadratic models. Other possibility may be transforming the data (using logarithms) in order to get straight lines and compare their slopes. What do you think about it?

Comment: It's not clear that either ANOVA or re-expressing the variables would be good ways to deal with the behaviors I asked about. Using ANOVA indicates you wish to compare means, but the possibility of applying logarithms suggests you don't care about means *per se* nor even about the form of the regression model.  There is still just too much missing information to support formulating an opinion about how to proceed.